# creating an sqlite DB in memory vs using a tmpfs

Tags: sqlite

Is there any functional difference or advantage to using the SQLITE3 :memory db vs defining a db on a memory disk, like a tmpfs mount?  is there some use case where I should use one vs the other?

Answer (score 2):

Putting the database on a disk, even if it is a RAM disk, allows you to access the resulting file.

On the other hand, going through the OS to manage the file might be slower. (This is unlikely to be noticeable in practice.)
And you don't need to bother about inventing a file name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access database from multiple processes => go with tmpfs.

If you want to keep data until operating system restarts => go with tmpfs.

If you want to keep data in a single process and flush data when process is killed => go with memory db.

SQLite is fast, and even faster when runs on ram (memory db/tmpfs). You really don't need to worry about performance of memory db vs tmpfs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).